# Magento Jquery issue with RWD Template

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento

I'm using Magento 1.9.1 with the RWD template with Augoria Slider on the home page and SM Gallery on the gallery page. They work fine so long as I remove

```
 <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/lib/jquery-1.10.2.min.js</name></action>
```

from app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/page.xml

This however causes the product description to vanish and I can't seem to get everything working together.

I tried creating a local.xml to only load the templates Jquery version on the product view page but this has not worked.

Website can be found here  http://goo.gl/KXNOL4

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to check couple of things first,

Check your Pluggin and remove any additional Jquery core library calls.

Check your script $ sign because, some times it cause conflict issues with prototype.

Also, I have gone through with your page and It gives below js errors.

Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined www.handcoded.co.uk/dart/skin/frontend/rwd/default/js/app.js:72
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined www.handcoded.co.uk/dart/skin/frontend/rwd/default/js/lib/jquery.cycle2.min.js:7
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined www.handcoded.co.uk/dart/skin/frontend/rwd/default/js/lib/jquery.cycle2.swipe.min.js:2
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function www.handcoded.co.uk/dart/skin/frontend/rwd/default/js/slideshow.js:26
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined www.handcoded.co.uk/dart/skin/frontend/rwd/default/js/lib/elevatezoom/jquery.elevateZoom-3.0.8.min.js:66

So seems like your jQuery library not loading..

Comment: I have removed Jquery from page.xml as it breaks the homepage slider and photo gallery. My question is how to enable Jquery for just the product view page without breaking anything else so that the product descriptions can be seen.

Comment: If you need to add Jquery only for product view, Open catalog.xml Go to <catalog_product_view translate="label"> handle, include your js in head area Ex:-     

<reference name="head">
  <action method="addJs"><script>your js file here</script></action>
</reference>